# Simple tabs in ReactJS using components

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js, I know basic stuff like state, components, but I need to:
Create a `MyTabsComponent` to be used like this:

```html
<MyTabsComponent>
  <div title={"Section title 1"}>Content of section 1</div>
  <div title={"Section title 2"}>Content of section 2</div>
  <div title={"Section title 3"}>Content of section 2</div>
  <div title={"Section title 4"}>Content of section 2</div>
  <div title={"Section title 5"}>Content of section 2</div>
  
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .and so on..............
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  
</MyTabsComponent>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[See visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvWtS.gif)

The above code should render like this:

```html
<div class="tabs">
        <button class="btn-active">Section title 1</button>
        <button class="btn">Section title 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Section title 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Section title 4</button>
        <!--
        
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        and so on..........
        -->
        
        <div class="view">
            Content of section 1
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I've tried:

```js
import React,{useState} from "react";

const MyTabsComponent = () => {
    const [title,setTitle] = useState(['Section 1','Section 2','Section 3']);
    const [ct,setCt] = useState(null);

    return (
        <div className="tabs">
        <TabButtons tabName={title} tabCt={setCt} />
        <div class="view">
           Content : {ct}
             </div>
    </div>
    );
};

const TabButtons = (props) => {
    return (
          <>
          {
              props.tabName.map((item,i)=>
              <button onClick={()=>props.tabCt(i)} className="btn">{item}</button>

              ) 
          }
            
            </>
    );
};

export default MyTabsComponent;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know how to do this **for any number of tabs.** Rest I can handle-- CSS, onClick events I understand well, as I know JS well.

EDIT: I found an article on Compound Components https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-react-compound-components/

and they say:

```js
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

//the name of this context will be DataContext
const DataContext = createContext({});

function Tab({ id, children }) {
  //extract the 'setActiveTabID` method from the DataContext state.
  const [, setActiveTabID] = useContext(DataContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setActiveTabID(id)}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
function TabPanel({ whenActive, children }) {
  //get the 'activeTabID' state from DataContext.
  const [activeTabID] = useContext(DataContext);
  return <div>{activeTabID === whenActive ? children : null}</div>;
}

function TabSwitcher(props) {
  const [activeTabID, setActiveTabID] = useState("a");
  //since this component will provide data to the child components, we will use DataContext.Provider
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={[activeTabID, setActiveTabID]}>
      {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default TabSwitcher;
export { Tab, TabPanel };
```

And to use:

```js
import TabSwitcher, { Tab, TabPanel } from "./TabSwitcher";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>TabSwitcher with Compound Components</h1>
      <TabSwitcher>
        <Tab id="a">
          <button>a</button>
        </Tab>
        <Tab id="b">
          <button>b</button>
        </Tab>

        <TabPanel whenActive="a">
          <div>a panel</div>
        </TabPanel>

        <TabPanel whenActive="b">
          <div>b panel</div>
        </TabPanel>
      </TabSwitcher>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The problem is: they are using

```
TabPanel
```

as a container whereas I want a `<div>`

Comment: this question itself need is whole application as answer

Comment: @AshishKamble question updated

Comment: Look into React **compound components**.

Comment: @morganney if you could please elaborate in answer.

Comment: @morganney I'd be grateful..i'd accept as an answer

Comment: By answer you mean do all the work? You have nothing done yet really, all you have is an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Here is the latest implementation for you

```
function TabController({ children }) {
  if (!children || children.length === 0) {
    return null
  }

  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = React.useState(children[0])

  return (
    <>
      {children.map((child) => (
        <button key={child.title} onClick={() => setCurrentTab(child)}>
          {child.props.title}
        </button>
      ))}
      <div className="view">{currentTab.props.children}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

This is how we use it

```
<TabController>
   <div title={'Section title 1'}>Content of section 1</div>
   <div title={'Section title 2'}>Content of section 2</div>
   <div title={'Section title 3'}>Content of section 3</div>
   <div title={'Section title 4'}>Content of section 4</div>
   <div title={'Section title 5'}>Content of section 5</div>
</TabController>
```

**OLD ANSWER**

I tried to create a simple component for you. You can implement actual data for TAB_DATA and pass it into your `MyTabsComponent` as props

```
//I mocked TAB_DATA here for testing purpose
const TAB_DATA = [
  {
    title: 'Section 1',
    content: 'Content 1',
  },
  {
    title: 'Section 2',
    content: 'Content 2',
  },
  {
    title: 'Section 3',
    content: 'Content 3',
  },
]

const MyTabsComponent = () => {
  const [ct, setCt] = useState(TAB_DATA[0].content) //set the first tab data as default

  return (
    <div className="tabs">
      {TAB_DATA.map((tab) => (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setCt(tab.content)
          }}
        >
          {tab.title}
        </button>
      ))}
      <div className="view">{ct}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is this for any number of `<div>` inside the component `MyTabsComponent`

Comment: You meant div for tab content?

Comment: I tried your code. You are passing data via `props`, I don't want to pass via `props`

Comment: Where do you want to keep tab data? I can modify my code for your requirement too

Comment: see @psikai 's answer below.

Comment: Understood your question. `TabPanel` is reasonable in this case, because `div` is a primitive element and not interactive in React context. If you want to have `div` as a container and have interaction, it's still achievable but it will be going against the core concept of React.

Comment: I understand, but what to do if I use `div` anyway?

Comment: I updated the answer with the latest implementation for the sake of your requirement. You can check it again. @user18270577

Comment: Can you help me in this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Szwe.png

Comment: it requires fully proper implementation... I can help you to understand the basics, and support you at the knowledge level. You can try to implement it at first and ask me if you have any questions. I also give you a related doc here which may help you in this requirement https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Where can I ask you? can you write the basic structure for that?

Comment: In your answer there's some error (in an IDE), have you tried it yourself?

Comment: I tried it locally, and it was able to show 5 tabs, what was the error did you have?

Comment: I think you didn't import `useState`, you need to import it like this `import React, {useState} from 'react'`

Comment: By the way, I updated the code for it `React.useState(children[0])`, now you can run it freely

Comment: @user18270577 please let me know if it does not run for you

Comment: please run your code there and share the working code as a answer here

Comment: Also, you are missing a `key` attribute in your button. for `map()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a component that has nested elements of an unknown number or type, then you need to make use of the `children` prop.  This is not something you have to define, but represents the child elements of the component when it is called.

Simply nest any number of components or elements between your component tags, and in `MyTabsComponent` pull out the `props` and put the `props.children` inside your return statement where you'd like them to go.

For your example, I have elevated the state `ct` and `title` to the parent component of `MyTabsComponent`, and given that state directly to the rendered buttons.  I also pass the `ct` to the `MyTabsComponent` so it can display its content.

###### MyTabsComponent

```
const MyTabsComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="tabs">
      {props.children}
      <div class="view">
        Content : {props.ct}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

###### The parent of MyTabsComponent

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Main = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(['Section 1','Section 2','Section 3']);
  const [ct, setCt] = useState(null);

  return (
    <MyTabsComponent ct={ct}>
      {title.map((item, i) =>
        <button onClick={() => setCt(i)} className="btn">{item}</button>
      )}
    </MyTabsComponent>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code? I am new to Reactjs; The code you shared- I was unable to make it completely work

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement your code

Comment: I updated my code and added more explanation.

Comment: Okay, I tried `class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
 return (
     <MyTabsComponent>...</MyTabsComponent>); } ` in the same file, I added the component. Is anything wrong

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));`

Comment: Can I get a bit of clarification what do you mean by Parent  of MyTabsComponent?

Comment: ERROR: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Comment: Yes, you can't use hooks like `useState` in a class component.  Your component `Main` needs to be refactored into a functional component.  Let me update again.

Comment: I made the update.  Parent component refers to the component that calls the child.  In this case `Main` is the parent, and `MyTabsComponent` is the child.

Comment: Can I use these two in the same file `index.js` where I've declared `const Main` and `const MyTabsComponent`

Comment: Yes, that is fine, although it would be better to eventually put them in the own files so that you can stay organized as your project grows.

Comment: index.js is as follows https://scrimba.com/scrim/c2zL7NtZ Please see the scrim and edit

Comment: Index should look like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hypatia-5b701h?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

The following code is used to clear all the test cases in **Codility React** test,  You can find the proper implementation below:

App.js:

```
import Tabs from './components/Tabs';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Tabs>
                <div title={'Section title 1'}>Content of section 1</div>
                <div title={'Section title 2'}>Content of section 2</div>
                <div title={'Section title 3'}>Content of section 3</div>
            </Tabs>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

MyTabsComponent:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyTabsComponent = ({ children }) => {
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

    const handleTabClick = index => setActiveIndex(index);

    return (
        <div className='tabs'>
            {children &&
                children.map((child, index) => {
                    if (!child.props.title) return undefined;

                    return (
                        <button
                            key={index}
                            className={index === activeIndex ? 'btn btn-active' : 'btn'}
                            disabled={index === activeIndex}
                            onClick={() => handleTabClick(index)}>
                            {child.props.title}
                        </button>
                    );
                })}

            {children && <div className='view'>{children[activeIndex]}</div>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyTabsComponent;
```

[image]